# Disabling IPv6 name/address support: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: cron, symfony, swiftmailer

I encountered the error quoted in the title, on Symfony3 and working with custom commands. There is this error, but also the fact that the mail is not sent. I cannot find a solution :

`sendmail: warning: inet_protocols: disabling IPv6 name/address support: Address family not supported by protocol`

`postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: disabling IPv6 name/address support: Address family not supported by protocol`

Here is the core of the matter :

my Command

```
class poke2WeekUserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('mr:poke-2-week-user')
            ->setDescription("Pokes users than havent't posted an advert for a while.")
            ->setHelp("Pokes users than havent't posted an advert for a while.")
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $cron = $this->getContainer()->get('mr_platform.cron');

        try {
            $cron->poke2WeekUser();
            $output->writeln('Ok !');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln('Error');
        }
    }
}
```

my Cron class

```
class Cron
{
  private $container;

  public function __construct($container){
    $this->container=$container;
  }

  public function poke2WeekUser(){
    $mailer=$this->container->get('mailer');
    $em=$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $repUser=$em->getRepository('MRUserBundle:User');
    $users=$repUser->findAll();
    $ans='';
    foreach($users as $user){
        if((int)$user->getCreationDate()->diff(new \Datetime())->d==14&&!$user->getPerson()){
            $mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
               ->setSubject("Subscription and advert posting")
               ->setFrom(array('info@mamyroom.fr' => 'MamyRoom'))
               ->setTo($user->getEmail())
               ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render('MRPlatformBundle:Common/Mail:poke2WeekUser.html.twig',array('user'=>$user)), 'text/html')
            ;
            $mailer->send($mail);
            $ans.='Sent to '.$user->getUsername().PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return new Response($ans);
  }
}
```

I will go past the injection of the container, and the 'use' statements.
What I find interesting (and quite odd) is that it works fine on my localhost (the error occurs on my distant server, with OVH)  : I assume that OS X and Linux have a different behaviour for this issue ?

I hope someone knows a bit of it ! Thanks in advance

Comment: UPDATE : There is this error, but also the fact that the mail is not sent.

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with PHP. This is a system-level warning issued from your mailer daemon.

Comment: Oops sorry, thank you, I didn't know tags were supposed to target the exact point

Comment: In fact I used this tag because I was not sure about the fact that this error had anything to do with the bug with the mail (not sending)

Comment: That's fine. I'm just pointing out that PHP wouldn't have anything to do with this. It's job is to walk your envelope down to the street corner and toss it into the mailbox. It's your mailbox (postfix, I'm guessing) that's complaining.

Comment: Ok thank you Marc, I didn't know postfix was involved, I thought it was sendmail

Comment: `postdrop` strongly suggests that you are on postfix. many mailers masquerade as sendmail, and the `sendmail` "binary" will just be a symlink to the mailer's own binary.

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information